# How do I get height of DirectWrite layout?

Tags: text, graphics, directx, direct2d, directwrite

I am aware that I can call `IDWriteTextLayout::GetMetrics`, but this gives me the boundaries of the text *including* space above and below the text for the ascender and descender, etc. However, what I'm looking for is the exact amount of space that the text *actually takes up*. How would I obtain or calculate this bounding box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GetMetrics()` together with `GetOverhangMetrics()`, subtracting overhang metrics from layout metrics will give you ink rectangle.